# "Tzon k'doshim!" ―"Baa!": source/provenance

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, animals, simchat-torah, provenance

In some synagogues, on *Simchas Tora*, someone will shout "*Tzon k'doshim!*", meaning "holy sheep/goats", or "*Tzon kadashim!*", meaning "sheep/goats of sacrificial-offering sanctity". He's replied to with "Baaaaa!".

Does anyone have any information on an early source for or mention of this custom?

Comment: Never seen this, but it sounds like fun.

Comment: I've seen this done in many shuls, I kinda find it a little degrading to the kids (who are usually the ones who respond).

Comment: @PM, "_tzon k'doshim_" is a term applied to Jews generally (don't ask me where). I don't think any insult is meant.

Comment: it's one thing to refer to them metaphorically that one, and another to command children to respond by bleating. I'm sure no insult was meant, but it is insulting none the less. Klall Yisroel are referred to as sheep for slaughter in Eicha and in some of the tisha b'av liturgy

Comment: I too have seen this custom. Perhaps [Ezek 36:38](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1236.htm#38) is related?

Comment: @DoubleAA, doubtless. Thanks. I'm editing the question in light of that and of old memories of mine.

Comment: I just want to point out that you can find among many kehillas very interesting minhagim on Simchas Torah...Perhaps I'll comment with some of them later

Comment: @Yehoshua, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8621

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is the custom of R. Yitzchok Ezrachi in the Mir Yeshiva in Yerushalayim, but I have no idea whether it was done in the earlier days of the yeshiva.

The practice must be at least a century old, considering that it is mentioned in a story written by the maskil D. Y. Silberbusch (see [here](http://benyehuda.org/silberbusch/tson_kedoshim.html) - published 1905), as well as in a story written by the maskil [Mendele Mocher Sforim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendele_Mocher_Sforim) (d. 1917), as noted [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_34306_265.pdf). Unfortunately I'm not aware of any early "traditional" source.

[Just found another maskil story, by Leon Kobrin, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=e648AQAAIAAJ&lpg=PA596&ots=LqIwRYi-tK&dq=&pg=PA597#v=onepage&q&f=false). Weird pattern!]

Answer (score 1):

The Ben Ish Chai in his sefer Ben Yoho'ada on Chumash says that the reason why the Bnei Yisroel are called "Tzon" is to remind us that we must serve Hashem with the four traits laid out by Yehuda Ben Teima in Pirkei Avos (5:20). Az KaNamer, audacious like a Leopard; Kal KaNesher, light like an eagle; Ruzt KaTzvi, run like a deer; Gibor Ka'Ari strong like a lion. The Roshie Teivos of these for animal Tzadi for Tzvi, Aleph for Ari, Nun for Nesher and Namer make up the word "Tzon". Hashem's flock must use all four of these character traits for avodas Hashem. If we do so then we are zocheh to be called "Tzon Kodshim" and be led by a merciful shepherd.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't see how it answers the question above, which asks for a source for or the provenance of the custom mentioned. Anyway, welcome to the site.

Comment: I thought Ben Yehoyada covers only Talmud. Maybe you're thinking of the book Ben Ish Chai in one of the divrei Torah that precede his discussion of halachah? At any rate, an exact citation would be nice

Comment: I have indeed seen a sefer Ben Yehoyada on Chumash. It can be purchased [here](http://www.wslibrary.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=3971) or [here](http://www.aron-hasfarim.co.il/product.asp?productid=2086).